# ifup fails to bring up interface every other time

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

I am getting strange issue where ifup fails every other run.  Here is the output as you can see it is in the pattern of fail, success, fail etc...:

```
bakalolo@User1:~/bashScripts$ sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp3s0
Configuring interface wlp3s0=wlp3s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlp3s0.pid -i wlp3s0 -D nl80211,wext -C /run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlp3s0.

bakalolo@User1:~/bashScripts$ sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp3s0
ifdown: interface wlp3s0 not configured
Configuring interface wlp3s0=wlp3s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlp3s0.pid -i wlp3s0 -D nl80211,wext -C /run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlp3s0.pid
wpa_supplicant: ctrl_interface socket located at /run/wpa_supplicant/wlp3s0
wpa_supplicant: configuring network block -- 0
wpa_supplicant: wpa-ssid "EmRtkGps2:cd:6b" -- OK
wpa_supplicant: wpa-psk ***** -- OK
wpa_supplicant: enabling network block 0 -- OK
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.42.150/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.42.255    dev wlp3s0 label wlp3s0
/bin/ip link set dev wlp3s0   up
 /bin/ip route add default via 192.168.42.10  dev wlp3s0 onlink 
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant

bakalolo@User1:~/bashScripts$ sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp3s0
Configuring interface wlp3s0=wlp3s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlp3s0.pid -i wlp3s0 -D nl80211,wext -C /run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlp3s0.

bakalolo@User1:~/bashScripts$ sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp3s0
ifdown: interface wlp3s0 not configured
Configuring interface wlp3s0=wlp3s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlp3s0.pid -i wlp3s0 -D nl80211,wext -C /run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlp3s0.pid
wpa_supplicant: ctrl_interface socket located at /run/wpa_supplicant/wlp3s0
wpa_supplicant: configuring network block -- 0
wpa_supplicant: wpa-ssid "EmRtkGps2:cd:6b" -- OK
wpa_supplicant: wpa-psk ***** -- OK
wpa_supplicant: enabling network block 0 -- OK
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.42.150/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.42.255    dev wlp3s0 label wlp3s0
/bin/ip link set dev wlp3s0   up
 /bin/ip route add default via 192.168.42.10  dev wlp3s0 onlink 
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

/etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#
auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.42.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.42.10
wpa-essid EmRtkGps2:cd:6b
wpa-psk emlidreach
```

edit:   Found a temp fixer upper if I type `sudo ifdown wlp3s0` before each `sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp3s0` it will run everytime but I still have no idea what the heck is going on??